# loads of extra queries CakePHP

Tags: mysql, cakephp

340I'm rebuilding a cakephp build at the moment and trying to figure out what's taking all the extra time and ram and so on, right now I'm just trying to understand what's happening here

I've found that there are like 30-40 mysql-calls like this on every page load:

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME = ?;
```

and I can't really find why and where that is, is this something needed for cake or has the old programmer shit the fan or is this just like "whatever"?

--------------- EDIT -----------------

I have now located the query in question to
a core file:

```
lib/Cake/Model/Datasource/Database/mysql.php
```

and the function:

```
getCharsetName ($name)
```

however I can't find where or why this is called

Comment: I you have exactly the same query 40 times in the same request then it could mean that your are creating 30-40 different connections or that some "clever" code was put in AppModel::__construct() or something central like that

Comment: This is not my code from the start so I'm not to familiar with it yet however the AppModel does not appear to have a __construct() at all

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like schema caching is disabled, or not working for some reason.

Check [**`Model::$cacheSources`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-Model.html#%24cacheSources), ideally it should be `true`. If it already is `true`, then you'll need to do some further debugging, check from where exactly `getCharsetName()` is being called, for example via exception stacktrace:

```
$e = new Exception();
debug($e->getTraceAsString());
```

Maybe your application is explicitly invoking the method, who knows. Also check what is passed for the `$name` parameter.

And make sure that `/tmp/cache/models/` is writable as well as readable.