# Why is my CakePHP query log filled with SELECT_CHARACTER_SET_NAME queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp, character-encoding

We have a site that gets a fair amount of traffic, and we have a query that seems to be executed every time a query is run. It is getting logged in a query log because it is sometimes slow.

```
SELECT CHARACTER_SET_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLLATIONS WHERE COLLATION_NAME= 'latin1_swedish_ci';
```

It appears to happen inside the getCharsetName() function, which is called from the describe() function. Does anyone happen to know why this is being called? Is there a way to make it go away? It seems unnecessary to call this EVERY time.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks Smash, but that was not helpful. There are no errors in our framework that would lead to this. It is not an error, but a log entry.

Comment: possible duplicate of [loads of extra queries CakePHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22473664/loads-of-extra-queries-cakephp)